# How to use in-built bisect to find the index of an item in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, bisection

```
D = [(20832049, "hello", 3), (2042449014, "bye", 2), (208414004814, "cya", 3)
```

I want to make a function with the arguments:

```
(key, D, hash)
```

where key represents the element at index[1] at each tuple, D is the dictionary example I gave, and hash is just to hash the key.

My aim is to create a function which finds the value of a tuple if there is a tuple in the list which has the same key or hash(key)

for example, if I did

```
get("hello", D, hash)
```

The function would return the value "3"

The list is already sorted

Comment: You want to write that function, so where is the problem? What's your question? Also: the title should be a *summary* of the contents of the body in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
def get(key, D, hash):
    for tuple in D:
        tuplelist = tuple.strip("()").split(", ")
        return (tuplelist[2] if tuplelist[1] == key)
```

Comment: That's not very efficient, compared to a bisection search